# htaccess QSA not working in Joomla 4

Tags: component, joomla-4.x, .htaccess-configuration

Migrating a Joomla 3 component to Joomla 4 I have problems with getting Apache Server htaccess correctly configured to append query string from request to substituted URL - QSA flag. - It looks like this affects other Joomla components as well. Here an example of an RewriteRule which works in Joomla 3 but produces a 404 in Joomla 4:

`RewriteRule ^testpage$ /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1 [QSA,L]`

It redirects but does not retain the original request when I change the rule to do so:

`RewriteRule ^testpage$ http://mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1 [QSA,L]`

This is what the user sees in the browser's address bar: `http://mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1`

Is it just me? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the context or background to what you are trying to do? Please provide an example of the original URL in full that contains `testpage` so we can see the before and after of what you have and what you want. I have a couple of ideas of what you might be trying to do but without some more details I would be just guessing at a solution.

Comment: Well, ```http://mydomain.com/testpage``` should stay in the address bar of the browser, but it redirects to the underlying component ```http://mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7```.

Comment: This Joomla component serves a printer supplies shop [link](https://www.druckertinte.de) with manufacturers https://www.druckertinte.de/hersteller, categories https://www.druckertinte.de/canon-modellserien, printer models, item lists https://www.druckertinte.de/canon-pixma%20ip%203600-ida8e0ef13 and item details. It relies heavily on htaccess redirects to find the appropriate records in the database. The links sends you to the current Joomla 3 version.

Comment: I am in the wrong country to to be able to view the link unfortunately. What I had in mind was the reverse to your requirement, remove the testpage but still go to the correct page.

Comment: In your example, the `QSA` flag is not actually required (unless you are requesting `/testpage?<something>`). Your second example would indeed trigger an external 302 (temporary) redirect. But does that "redirect" display the correct content (ie. the target URL does "work")? Where exactly are you putting this rule? The order of the mod_rewrite directives (in relation to the existing Joomla directives) is important. Please edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` with this rule in place.

Comment: "to append query string from request to substituted URL" - In your examples there is no query string on the request?

Comment: No there won't be query string in the url.

Anyways, I realised that I could write a custom router to achieve the same, and much more elegantly. 
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Comment: @user2802638 Glad you got it resolved. It would be great if you can put something down in an "answer" (and later accept it) as this could help other readers. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in Joomla there is a better way to solve this issue than using mod_rewrite. A big advantage seems to be that you do not have to rely only on the Apache server, i.e. if you want to use nginx.

Here some links I found on how to write a Custom Router in Joomla:

For Joomla 4

- https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book/com-router.html
- https://youtu.be/zqyjRuVaT8M
- [Router for Joomla 4](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/31515/router-for-joomla-4)

For Joomla 3

- https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

If you know of better tutorials, feel free to post your links to this topic.

Edit:
This thread should also be helpful:
[Joomla 4 Router forward to Controller function](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33319/joomla-4-router-forward-to-controller-function)