# Joomla 4 Router forward to Controller function

Tags: joomla-4.x, .htaccess-configuration, router, routing

For a Joomla 4 component I just cannot figure out how to successfully forward or call a Controller function from within a custom Router.

This is the Controller - it basically loads an image:

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\Component\Myproject\Site\Controller;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Image\Image;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;


class ImageController extends BaseController
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function show()
    {
        $id = $app->input->get('id', \null, 'string');
        // ... logic to load the image 
    }
}
```

Using this URL the image shows up:

```
/index.php?option=com_myproject&task=image.show&id=123
```

To support SEF URLs inside the component the URL gets called like this:

```
/img/product_12312.jpg
```

In Joomla 3 I did this by configure mod_rewrite in the .htaccess. Now this should get done by the Router:

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\Component\Myproject\Site\Service;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterBase;


class Router extends RouterBase
{
    
    public function parse(&$segments)
    {
        $total = \count($segments);

        $vars  = [];

        switch ($segments[0]) {
            case ('img'):

                $vars['id'] = str_replace('.jpg', '', explode('_', $segments[1])[1]);
                $vars['task'] = 'image.show';
                break;
        }
        // print_r($vars); // seems to work so far
        
        return $vars;
    }
    // .... other code
}
```

The parse() function correctly splits the URL into the $vars array().

When I call the SEF image URL in the browser, I get a 404 error. - What am I missing to internally call the show() function of the ImageController class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up in https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Upgrading_to_Joomla4#Router what I found were the differences in the router between v3 and v4. In particular you have to find the `Itemid` in the `preprocess()` function and you also now have to unset the segments in `parse()` otherwise you'll get a 404.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unsetting the segments in the parse() did the trick. ```foreach ($segments as $key => $segment) {unset($segments[$key]);}```

I did not need a menu item to access my controller. So I did not overwrite the preprocess() in my RouterBase. 

Since the code was not using the router to build URLs, I simply added an build() to the RouterBase that just returns an empty segments array like this ```public function build(&$query) { $segments = []; return $segments;}``` 

Very valuable overview and video tutorial indeed. Thanks again!