# Rewrite rule in htaccess in joomla 4?

Tags: joomla-4.x, url, .htaccess-configuration

In J3 i used specific rewrite rules in `.htaccess` that worked fine but doesn't seem to work in J4. Here's an example :

`RewriteRule ^metier/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\.html$ /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=102&filtrefonction=$1 [QSA,L]`

In J4, when I use this URL in my browser it works fine :

```
/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=102&filtrefonction=$1
```

but when I try the rewritten URL :

```
/metier/btp-construction.html
```

I get a 404 error Page not found... `RewriteEngine` is `On` of course and the rules in the `.htaccess` file.

I have tried to change the rule this way :

`RewriteRule ^metier-([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\.html$ /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=102&filtrefonction=$1 [QSA,L]`

and try to call the url

```
/metier-btp-construction-usines-infrastructures-tp.html
```

but it gives the same result : an error 404 :/

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?
Thanks for any answer!

Comment: I had a similar issue and ended up using the Joomla Router in favour of htaccess [https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33283/htaccess-qsa-not-working-in-joomla-4/33295#33295](link)

Comment: "when I use this URL in my browser it works fine : `/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=102&filtrefonction=$1`" - Presumably you replaced `$1` with `btp-construction` (in your example)? Where exactly have you put this rule in the `.htaccess` file? A rule like this would need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, before the Joomla code block (front-controller pattern).

Comment: Your regex character class (`[a-zA-Z0-9-_]`) is a little ambiguous (although should be OK in this case as it happens) since you have an unescaped _literal hyphen_ that is not the first or last character. It would be "safer" to move the literal hyphen to the last position (switching the last two characters), ie. `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`